# JSON support for companion object

Tags: json, scala, spray

I have a class that looks somewhat like that

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime

import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

sealed trait Person {

  def firstName: String

  def country: String

  def lastName: String

  def salary: Option[BigDecimal]
}

case class InternalPerson(
                     firstName: String,
                     country: String,
                     lastName: Option[BigDecimal],
                     salary: Option[BigDecimal]
                    ) extends Person

object Person {
  def fromName(name: Name, country: String, salary: Option[BigDecimal]): Person = {
    InternalPerson(
              firstName = name.firstName,
              lastName = name.lastName,
              country = country,
              salary = salary
              )
  }
}

object PersonJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val personFormat = jsonFormat4(Person.apply)
}
```

I am just trying to add a json support to my class. whenever I import the protocol and `spray.json._` from another classes I get:

`Note: implicit value personFormat is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type`

and

`value apply is not a member of object of Person`

any idea on how to have Json support for companion objects that extends a trait in scala?

Comment: Actually Person doesn't take 4 params right? Person is an object. And you haven't defined your apply method too in your person object. I would suggest to marshall/unmarshall into the class and from there, you can use object apply's to convert them to relevant format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined your implicit in terms of the case class, InternalPerson, json formatting should be enabled:  `implicit val personFormat = jsonFormat4(InternalPerson)`

And you won't have to define an apply() method, which you will have to do in either the Person trait or any implementation thereof otherwise.

Comment: Re Shankar's comment above, Yes, figure out how many params Person and InternalPerson ought to take. If only 3 params, then the implicit I suggested ought to be: ...jsonFormat3(InternalPerson)

Answer (score 1):

You can use play framework to deal with Json.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson

I think it's very easy and intuitive.

For primitive types it's enough to use `Json.format[ClassName]`. If you have something more complex you can write your own `writes` and `reads`. I know that this question is about spray, but another solution can be good.

So for example for `InternalPerson` it'll be:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class InternalPerson {
  firstName: String,
  country: String,
  lastName: Option[BigDecimal],
  salary: Option[BigDecimal]
)

object InternalPerson {
  implicit val format = Json.format[InternalPerson]
}
```

In case that you want to do it with `Trait` it will be the same. Sometimes you need to write explicitly reads and writes.